# Отправить запрос на сервер с Андроид

Tags: asp.net, android, java

Добрый вечер.

Делаю один небольшой сервич и появился неразрешимый и, главное, непонятный для меня вопрос.
Есть АПИ, которое расположено по адресу:
http://domen.com/API/XML/APIManager.ashx

В документации написано, что нужно отправить запрос с заголовком: GetMethod и содержанием:

```
<Request>
 <Header>
 <Authentication>
 <Login>string(32)</Login>
 <Pass>string(14)</Pass>
 </Authentication>
 <Request>int</Request>
 </Header>
</Request>
```

Как реализовать такой запрос на Андроид, чтобы получить ответ от сервера?

Большое спасибо!

Comment: @ilyarasputin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(<YOUR_URL_HERE>);

try {
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( <YOUR_XML_HERE>, HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));        
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Также не забывайте, что работа с сетью в основном потоке **запрещена**.

Comment: так, на всякий случай [link][1]


  [1]: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php